# External php file that is loaded into index.php with .load() method not recognising $_SESSION variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

So my main page loads other php pages into it with click of a button so it can be a single page website without having to load all the content at once.

**index.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<head>
$('#btnPetShop').one( "click", function(){
            $( "#page_shop" ).load( "shop.php" );
        });
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo session_status();/----Always returns 1, no matter if logged in or not----/
if(isset($_SESSION['admin']))
        {
            if($_SESSION['admin']==1)
                {
                    /----this part works, I am logged in as admin----/
                }
        }
?>
<div id="page_shop"></div>
</body>
```

**shop.php**

```
<?php

        if(isset($_SESSION['admin']))
        {
            if($_SESSION['admin']==1)
                {

                }
            else{}
        }
        else{}  <----I end up here as if $_SESSION['admin'] is not set----/


        /----code entered here loads fine----/
?>
```

The idea is to make a delete and edit button (if you are logged in as admin) on every article in shop.php.
Problem is that $_SESSION['admin'] is recognized on index.php, but not inside shop.php

I tried typing the content of shop.php directly into  and it works, the problem is that i want it to load with a click of a button.

Comment: Try adding `session_start();` in your shop.php file.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Shouldn't it be too much since session_start(); is on top of my index.php that I never leave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well okay, I feel dumb... I found the solution.

I had this as a script

```
$('#btn_logout').click(function(){
            <?php session_destroy();?>
        });
```

This is a big no no and if you do this you should be ashamed

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `session_start();` in each page that needs access to the session data.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

**EDIT**

Since the solution mentioned in my original answer does not work for you and `session_status()` returns 1 in your code, it means sessions are enabled on your server. There is only one thing left which could explain that your sessions are lost:

You are loading `shop.php` with an AJAX request, is the URL exactly in the same domain as `index.php`? Try to add the full path before `shop.php` to see if this solves the issue.

Just to be clear, if your `index.php` runs on `http://localhost/test/index.php`, your new code will be:

```
$( "#page_shop" ).load( "http://localhost/test/shop.php" );
```

Comment: Still doesn't work

Shouldn't it be too much since session_start(); is on top of my index.php that I never leave?

Comment: No, it's not enough. Each HTTP request starts fresh. When you load shop.php via an AJAX call, you are starting a new HTTP request, and the PHP server loads it as if you browsed to the file directly in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever ( in any PHP page) if you want to use any Session variable then you have to first declare `session_start();` so, in your case if you have $_SESSION['admin']="User1234" on index.php and if you want to use value of $_SESSION['admin'] in shop.php then you have to again declare session_satart(); and then use it. For example, If let consider that index.php has session variable $_SESSION['admin']="User1234" and now you want to print "Welcome User1234" on shop.php then you can do it as shown below.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['admin'] = "User1234";
?>
```

**Shop.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "Welcome, ". $_SESSION['admin']
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Welcome, User1234
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, i tried session start on every page.

BTW:

My session stays if i refresh with Shift+R, but goes away if i press enter on url bar (go to index.php again)

Are my xampp settings bad? ( i have session autostart off in php.ini, but session start on every php page)

Comment: Did you add session_start(); at top of the page in php tags in shop.php?